# How to make text block fixed and not overlap above other elements?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a new page on Wordpress, it is more or less completed now but I have one problem.

I need the text on the left-hand side of the page properly fixed but it keeps going above the footer once you scroll to the bottom.

I want it to remain fixed but not go past the last box on all screen sizes, how would I do that?

I have tried the following CSS:

```
position: fixed; 
width: 20% !important;
float: left !important;
```

Here is a link to the page - https://marketing.feedinfo.com/recruitment-2/

Comment: show us more of your code

Comment: It's done through a builder, so I've not inputted any HTML. Only added CSS for the styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this solution.

in this solution text will not hide.

```css
#left-col {
    position: sticky;
    /* width: 20% !important; */
    float: left !important;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 190px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your footer css

```
position: relative
z-index: 1000
```

Comment: That only hides the text behind the footer?

Comment: @AdamMaulvi yeah it does, it is the cleanes way to handle this problem. the complex javacript way is too much unnecessarily complicated

Comment: I understand that, although I still need the text visible at all times